# What are the JAXB Jar files to be used with Java 17 project

Tags: java, java-8, jaxb, java-17

I am in the middle of upgrading my project from Java 8 to Java 17. My project use JAXB related JAR files. However, I am getting a lot of error while compiling the project and most of them are related to JAXB. Can anyone please help me with JAXB related JAR files and their version I should be using in my project for Java 17? Also, please suggest the compatible JAVA EE release I should be using.

Comment: Well, you should be able to get the relevant information yourself via a quick google search. If you want to go for Jakarta EE (formerly Java EE) you'd get Jaxb as well so I'd use the respective versions. For Jakarta EE compatibility, could could refer here (result of a quick search): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_EE

Answer (score 9):

In Java 8 and earlier, JAXB was integrated within JVM itself, but this was changed in Java 9. Because of the modularization of the JVM (Project Jigsaw), JAXB and some others were removed from JDK. This doesn't mean JAXB is no longer supported, just that it´s another dependency that needs to be on the classpath.

Due to JavaEE / Jakarta EE having breaking changes regarding namespace, the right dependency coordinates depends on what kind of enterprise specification is used.

In case of JavaEE 8 - the `javax.*` namespace - the correct dependency is:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and the dependency compilant with JakartaEE - the `jakarta.*` namespace - is:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. What are the other Jar files that is needed to add like jaxb-impl, jaxb-core, etc. and what should their version to work with JDK 17.

Comment: @AnjitSingha, it worked for you ?. This is Not working for me , can you please help me on this ?

Comment: The question asked about Java 17, not Java 8.  This answer isn't helpful.

Comment: I've never ever mentioned that is a Java 8 based solution. I wrote a JavaEE 8 and a JakartaEE solution. Java 8 is totally different than JavaEE 8

Answer (score 2):

I'm running Java 17.0.5 2022-10-18 LTS and this worked for me:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2):

When i added the following dependencies, worked for Spring boot 3.1.4 and Java 17 version.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Begin to migrate **from Java 8 to Java 11** first.

Then read for example articles like *Removal of Java EE and CORBA Modules* in Java 11 (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/migrate/index.html#JSMIG-GUID-561005C1-12BB-455C-AD41-00455CAD23A6) : JAXB and JAX-WS are no longer bundled with JDK.

Or this one : https://learn.microsoft.com/java/openjdk/transition-from-java-8-to-java-11

So you will need to add JAX-B for example.

With Maven:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

However an implementation may be also necessary.

Like :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the JAXB dependencies that I use in [hisrc-higherjaxb-sample-jaxbplugins (zip)](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/releases/download/2.1.0/hisrc-higherjaxb-sample-jaxbplugins-2.1.0-mvn-src.zip), a JAXB 4.x sample project built using JDK 17. Focus on the dependencies below [hisrc-basicjaxb-runtime](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb#readme), in this dependency tree, for the answer to your question.

```
org.patrodyne.jvnet:hisrc-higherjaxb-sample-jaxbplugins:jar:2.1.0
+- org.patrodyne.jvnet:hisrc-basicjaxb-runtime:jar:2.1.0:compile
|  +- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:2.1.1:compile
|  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:4.0.0:compile
|  +- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:4.0.2:compile
|  |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-core:jar:4.0.2:compile
|  |     +- org.eclipse.angus:angus-activation:jar:2.0.0:runtime
|  |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:4.0.2:compile
|  |     \- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:4.1.1:compile
|  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.11.0:compile
|  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:2.0.6:compile
\- org.patrodyne.jvnet:hisrc-basicjaxb-testing:jar:2.1.0:test
   +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.9.2:test
   |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
   |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.9.2:test
   |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
   \- xmlunit:xmlunit:jar:1.6:test
```

> Note: The [4.x](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/xml-binding/4.0/) release of the JAXB [API](https://github.com/jakartaee/jaxb-api/tree/4.0.0-RELEASE), [RI](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/tree/4.0.2-RI-RELEASE/jaxb-ri) and [ZIP](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-ri/4.0.2/) uses the latest [JAXB Schema Binding 3.0 Specification](https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_3_0.xsd) for [Jakarta EE 10](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.jaxb-impl/releases/4.0.0).